# Synonyms and antonyms of "specific"

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

I am trying to come up with the names for the following two classes
*1) Design-specification-specific

2) Design-specification-agnostic*

Somehow I feel that these can be named better. You can help with the names or with the synonyms and antonyms of the word "specific" in the above mentioned context.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest (I would also read and immediatly understand the following expressions):

1. Design-specification-dependent
2. Design-specification-independent

Comment: @Chappo I'm using this solution right now, though I found it here first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language-independent_specification

Comment: @Chappo: It's not obvious to me why daniel's suggestion needs "justification". In this specific context (and, *in general*, I feel) ***dependent / independent*** are perfectly natural terms, whereas OP's original ***specific / agnostic*** is a slightly quirky pair of opposites. But clearly the reason an alternative is needed is simply because *design-specification-specific* involves clumsy repetition of related terms having unrelated meanings. daniel's suggestion doesn't, so it looks good to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: the point is not that daniel's answer should look good but that should be a useful solution. His edit improves it, but for someone looking for the *most reliable* answer, there's currently nothing to indicate that this isn't just one person's uninformed opinion. Your own comment, if it were incorporated into the answer, would address this, because it explains why this solution works. Or daniel could cite his own expertise in a relevant field or occupation. It's not a big deal, I simply thought the original answer was low quality, and now it's been improved. Comment deleted.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: feel free to make a better answer from your argument (which I wouldn't formulate better) and incorporate my initial suggestion. Then I will remove my rather short answer.

Comment: @daniel: No-one (not even *you!* :) has upvoted the question, and very likely the OP himself will never return to even accept your answer (which no-one apart from me has upvoted, though *in context* I feel it's more than adequate). Please feel free to incorporate ***any*** text I write anywhere on ELU (as comments or answers) into your own posts. But my personal position is that whereas I might have answered this on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), I think it's a bit trivial for ELU. In short - edit your own answer and see if that gets you some upvote rep! :)